# Extract first <li> tag entries from a post content?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a custom excerpt for an education website. It has posts that contains `<ul>` and `<ol>` listing. I want to print the first child of both **ul** and **ol** tags from the post.
Currently, I have the following code that can print only the first paragraph.

```php
    function wpden_excerpt()
    {
        global $post;

       $output = get_the_content();

    $wanted_number_of_paragraph = 1;

    $tmp = explode ('</li>', $output);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $wanted_number_of_paragraph; ++$i) {
       if (isset($tmp[$i]) && $tmp[$i] != '') {
           $tmp_to_add[$i] = $tmp[$i];
       }
    }
    $output = implode('</li>', $tmp_to_add) . '</li>';

        echo $output;

    }
```

**HTML Content:**

```
<p>Once in a blue moon</p>
<p>Meaning</p>
<ul>
  <li>not very often</li>
  <li>rarely</li>
  <li>once after a long time</li>
</ul>
<p>Examples</p>
<ol>
  <li>My sister lives in Alaska, so I only see her once in a blue moon.</li>
  <li>Once in a blue moon, there's an issue I can't resolve.</li>
  <li>That company puts on a good performance only once in a blue moon.</li>
</ol>
```

**Printing custom excerpt with:**

```
<?php wpden_excerpt(); ?>
```

*Now I want to print something like that out of the HTML Content:*

```
<p>
<b>Meaning:</b> not very often<br /> <!-- Content from first <li> of first <ul> -->
<b>Example:</b> My sister lives in Alaska, so I only see her once in a blue moon. <!-- Content from first <li> of first <ol> -->
</p>
```

Comment: What's your exact question? There is nothing in that code that parses `li` tags

Comment: We can replace p tag with li

Comment: Sounds fine - why not do it?

Comment: I've changed it. I am not very good in PHP, but it works well with p tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<?php
$post = "<p>Once in a blue moon</p>
<p>Meaning</p>
<ul>
<li>not very often</li>
<li>rarely</li>
<li>once after a long time</li>
</ul>
<p>Examples</p>
<ol>
<li>My sister lives in Alaska, so I only see her once in a blue moon.</li>
<li>Once in a blue moon, there's an issue I can't resolve.</li>
<li>That company puts on a good performance only once in a blue moon.</li>
</ol>";

$arr1 = explode("</li>",explode("<ul>", $post)[1]);
$arr2 = explode("</li>",explode("<ol>",$post)[1]); 



echo "<p>
<b>Meaning:</b>".substr($arr1[0],4)."<br /><b>Example:</b>".substr($arr2[0],4)."</p>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Hardood! We are pretty close. This is the output:

`<p>
<b>Meaning:</b>
<ul>
<li>not very often<br /> 
<b>Example:</b>
<ol>
<li>My sister lives in Alaska, so I only see her once in a blue moon.</p>`

How to replace these empty tags?

Comment: use substr($arr2[0],8) and substr($arr[3],8) to axtract the text from ul li and ol li

Comment: I have already edited the original code to reflect the update

Comment: Used it .substr($arr2[0],10). and .substr($arr3[0],10). Working well!

But we have to get the html data from the_content() function that display all the posts.

How to use it in variable or something like that?

Comment: Yes, your code is working. But to implement that I have to get data from the_content() not static HTML.
I don't know how to do that. Can you help please?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/

It reads data from database.

Comment: Read PHP in my question and find this:

`function wpden_excerpt()
{
    global $post;

   $output = get_the_content();

$wanted_number_of_paragraph = 1;

$tmp = explode ('</li>', $output);
for ($i = 0; $i < $wanted_number_of_paragraph; ++$i) {
   if (isset($tmp[$i]) && $tmp[$i] != '') {
       $tmp_to_add[$i] = $tmp[$i];
   }
}
$output = implode('</li>', $tmp_to_add) . '</li>';

    echo $output;

} `

Comment: try to use your ($output) variable in your code instead of my static html variable ($post)

Comment: I tried, it's picking up right data but there is little problem with empty tags. See this is the output:

`<p>
<b>Meaning:</b> paragraph -->

<!-- wp:list -->
<ul><li>not very often<br /> 
<b>Example:</b> paragraph -->

<!-- wp:list {"ordered":true} -->
<ol><li>My sister lives in Alaska, so I only see her once in a blue moon.</p>`

Not extracting exactly li data but with some neighboring tags.

Comment: again, i edited the original code above for you, please try it, i hope it works

Comment: Wonderful! But still there is one more empty <li> tag after </b>

`<p>
<b>Meaning:</b><li>not very often<br /><b>Example:</b><li>My sister lives in Alaska, so I only see her once in a blue moon.</p>`

Last thing to remove

Comment: Hurray! got it!

`$arr1 = explode("</li>",explode("<ul><li>", $output)[1]);
$arr2 = explode("</li>",explode("<ol><li>",$output)[1]);`

Comment: also you can use substr($arr1[0],4), substr($arr2[0],4) respectively as i did it above on the last edited version of the code

Comment: Right! But it seems good. I am testing it on Wordpress. Tell you the final result.

Comment: See it here buddy!

`function wpden_excerpt() {
    
   global $post;
   $output = get_the_content();

$arr1 = explode("</li>",explode("<ul><li>", $output)[1]);
$arr2 = explode("</li>",explode("<ol><li>",$output)[1]); 
echo "<p>
<b>Meaning:</b> ".$arr1[0]."<br /><b>Example:</b> ".$arr2[0]."</p>";
 }`

Is it fine now?

By the way I am really thankful of you!

Answer (score 0):

Does this method work for you?

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var _ul_f = $('ul li:first').text();
   var _ol_f = $('ol li:first').text();

   $('#output').html('<p><b>Meaning:</b>'+_ul_f+'</br><b>Example:</b>'+_ol_f+'</p>');
});
</script>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: In WordPress, jQuery is already installed, so you shouldn't add jquery 3.2.1 on top of that.  It causes problems.

Comment: @HowardE jQuery call can be avoided simply if it's already there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am looking for PHP solution.

Comment: @JuniperScott Using jQuery can make life easy. Still that script can be embedded via WordPress hook - add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_js_to_wp_footer' ). Here is my [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gKVy9EOy1MSjrAqEVhXpTXSYgNW03Gix/view)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOMDocument load the HTML and then get the children of each block. using `childNodes` and `nodeValues`. By placing your HTML in variables, this allows you to parse each variable separately. Simply echo out your variable on the page to display its content.

```php
$ulcontent = "
<p>Once in a blue moon</p>
<p>Meaning</p>
<ul>
  <li>not very often</li>
  <li>rarely</li>
  <li>once after a long time</li>
</ul>
";
$olcontent = "
<p>Examples</p>
<ol>
  <li>My sister lives in Alaska, so I only see her once in a blue moon.</li>
  <li>Once in a blue moon, there's an issue I can't resolve.</li>
  <li>That company puts on a good performance only once in a blue moon.</li>
</ol>
";
$uldom = new DOMDocument;
$uldom->loadHTML($ulcontent);

$oldom = new DOMDocument;
$oldom->loadHTML($olcontent);

$firstChildOfUl = $uldom->getElementsByTagName('li')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0);
$ulvalue = $firstChildOfUl->nodeValue;

$firstChildOfOl = $oldom->getElementsByTagName('li')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0);
$olvalue = $firstChildOfOl->nodeValue;

echo "<PRE>",var_dump($ulvalue),"</PRE>";
echo "<PRE>",var_dump($olvalue),"</PRE>";
```

OUTPUT:

**First Child of UL:** `string(14) "not very often"`
**First Child of OL:** `string(65) "My sister lives in Alaska, so I only see her once in a blue moon."`

HTML on PHP page:

```html
<?=$ulcontent?>
<?=$olcontent?>
```

HTML OUTPUT of : `<?=$ulcontent?>` & `<?=$olcontent?>`

Once in a blue moon

Meaning

not very often
rarely
once after a long time
Examples

My sister lives in Alaska, so I only see her once in a blue moon.
Once in a blue moon, there's an issue I can't resolve.
That company puts on a good performance only once in a blue moon.

Comment: Sorry, but we have to get the data from the_content() function that display more than one posts.